# What is the difference between docs and documents properties in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

What is the difference between the two codes -
snapshot.documents is showing a warning.
So I used `.docs` instead of it, but now my code isn't working.

```
void messagesStream() async{
    await for(var snapshot in _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()) {
      for(var message in snapshot.documents) {
        print(message.data());
      }
    }
  }

                                 AND



 void messagesStream() async{
    await for(var snapshot in _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()) {
      for(var message in snapshot.docs) {
        print(message.data());
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: i don't know your mean, i not found docs api

Answer (score 0):

These properties are belonging to Firebase Firestore, not Flutter, and they mean the same and the way you work with them is the same, but on Aug 19, 2020, Google has announced a new round of updates for Firebase packages for Flutter, some of the changes are large and braking so you have to read the official new docs for [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs).

The part that describes the change in the `documents` property from the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#firestore):

> DEPRECATED: documents has been deprecated in favor of docs.

Check the migration part in the new docs to migrate your app to the new updates:
[FlutterFire Migration](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration)

**Make sure you read the documentation carefully because there is a new initialization you have to do**